# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget

Tags: android

I'm using a `BitmapFactory` to decode a JPG from file and then setting the `imageBitmap` of an `ImageView` with that. Sometimes, the app crashes with "`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget`"

I've tried using:

```
BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
options.inSampleSize = 2;
Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filepath, options);
```

it seemed to be working for  a while, but not anymore. What can I do?

Comment: what is the image resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Android, there is a cap on how much memory that can be allocated to an application, it could be around 16 MB to 32 MB. (Upto Android Version)

For a 2 Mega Pixel, memory required for the bitmap would be 2 * 4 = 8 M.

To reduce memory consumption, you need to lower the image resolution. Say WVGA, 800x480 to start with

Shash

Comment: so right now, i have the Camera.Parameters set to setJpegQuality(100). I guess I need to change that?

Comment: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#setPictureSize%28int,%20int%29

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the number of images you use, or cache them, and if you cache them, store them in the minimum size you need.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: How do I store them in a particular size?

Comment: This way to resize them : http://www.anddev.org/resize_and_rotate_image_-_example-t621.html

Answer (score 0):

And this is the code to cache image files.

```
protected static Map<String, Drawable> cacheThumbs = new HashMap<String, Drawable>();
```

//code to cache images

```
                if( thumbUri.length() == 0 )
                    return;
                Drawable d = cacheThumbs.get( thumbUri );
                if( d == null )
                {
                    String fileName = movie.getId()+"_"+thumbUri.substring( thumbUri.lastIndexOf('/')+1 );
                    cacheFile = new File( application.getCacheDir(), fileName );
                    if( !cacheFile.exists() )
                    {
                        //Log.v(LOG_TAG,"Fetching "+thumbUri +" and caching in "+cacheFile.getAbsolutePath() );
                        InputStream bis = (InputStream) new URL(thumbUri).getContent();
                        BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream( new FileOutputStream( cacheFile ) );
                        int read = 0;
                        while( (read = bis.read( buffer )) != -1 )
                            bos.write( buffer, 0, read );
                        bis.close();
                        bos.close();                         
                        Log.v(LOG_TAG,thumbUri + " fetched");
                    }//if
                    Log.v(LOG_TAG,thumbUri + " in cache");
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream( new FileInputStream( cacheFile ), 9000 );
                    d = Drawable.createFromStream( bis, "src name");
                    bis.close();
                    cacheThumbs.put( thumbUri, d );
```

Regards,
 Stéphane

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add a different view to this discussion. I did read so many threads and suggestions and ended up with a WebView to display single images. It's not ment for galleries just for a single image. It's working perfect, its zoomable by options, its scrollable and finally no memory errors ;-)

It works for images you load from the web and for local images as well. Here's a small example:

```
WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_webview);

String html = "<html><head><title>A title</title></head><body bgcolor=\"#000000\"><img src=\"" + url + "\"></body></html>";

WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
webSettings.setLoadWithOverviewMode(true);
webSettings.setSupportZoom(true);   
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);

webView.setScrollbarFadingEnabled(true);
webView.setScrollBarStyle(WebView.SCROLLBARS_OUTSIDE_OVERLAY);
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("fake://fake.com", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", null);
```